# Python & mongoDB: Monitor database changes and push changes to clients via websocket

Tags: python, django, mongodb, monitor

Im writing the backend of an app using Django 1.10 and mongoDB.
The mongoDB database is populated by an external program (not Django).
Django accepts websockets, and when a mongoDB change is registered, the websocket should push the new data to clients via websockets.

**Question:** Is it possible for Django to get notified when a mongoDB database is changed (insert, update, delete)?

I have looked at [this lib](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/monitoring.html), and if this is the answer I would love to see a working example.

I can imaging the approach would look something like this:

```
@channel_session
def ws_receive(message):
    # If message == 'subscribe' and channel == 'mongoDB'
    # Listen for mongoDB changes and push changes to client
```

Comment: The basics of any such operation is a [tailable cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/) on the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) which is present on any MongoDB "Replica Set". Note that a "Replica Set" can even be a single member if so desired, but it's also the only way the "oplog" is actually present. You can find examples of implementing a tailable cursor quite easily, but as for how exactly to communicate any "changes" over a websocket, becomes either too broad or begins to recommend software that already does this.